# Android app, edit existing TextView using code?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have just gone through the android "first app" tutorial located [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), and I want to start experimenting on my own with the stuff that tutorial taught me.

What I want to do is take the message the user writes in the first activity, and display it in a TextView element, which i have defined in the XML file for the second activity. How do I edit the properties of a text view using the java code? I have no idea how to edit any of the properties of the element, even though I know its `android:id` . Can anyone give me any insight into this?

Comment: what you need exertly?? edittext data write in first activity show in second activity??

Comment: yes. I have 2 activities, the first with a button and editable text field, the button triggers a method which gets the text from the editable text field and creates an intent, and attaches an extra string with the contents of the editable text field. I want to be able to edit the text of an already existing TextView object in the second activity, which is defined in the xml for that activity.

Comment: in second activity just getdata from intent and set this data into textview
as likw below ANSWERS

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_the_textview);
textView.setText(yourNewText);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is take the message the user writes in the first activity

I assume you'll use an EditText in your FirstActivity, so you have to get the text from this widget and pass it as an extra in your intent used to switch to the second activity.

In your FirstActivity onCreate method it will look like :

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
Intent i = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
i.putExtra("myText", myEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

And in your SecondActivity onCreate methode :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getExtras().getString("myText");
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
myTextView.setText(text);
```

Comment: OK, I understand the methodology behind it a bit more now, however it appears that the line `TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);` is not actually creating the instance of TextView, as when I press "send" to launch the activity, i get an error: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: this implies that the myTextView object does not exist, as I ran a `System.out.println` and checked that the string was definitely there.

Comment: Without your code it's hard to guess. Is your setContentView(...) correct ? Did you specify the correct id in your layout and in the findViewById(...) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalculate);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String text = editText.getText().toString();

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Calculated.class);
             myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
             startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Calculated.java**

```
public class Calculated extends Activity {

TextView mTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculated);

       mTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

       mTextview.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
}
```

**calculated.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```